# Перемещение видимой области на картинке с учетом всех соотношений сторон (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

У меня есть область для загрузки изображения с соотношением сторон 4:3. После загрузки появляется сетка из различных соотношений: 1:1, 3:4, 16:9, 16:5. В центре этой сетки находится видимая область, остальная часть затемняется. Пользователь может навести курсор на область, которая представляет собой пересечение всех разрешений. По клику на эту область он может перемещать её куда угодно, но в пределах изображения. Если пользователь переместит область, например, в левый верхний угол, все соотношения должны подстроиться так, чтобы область оказалась вверху слева. При этом прямоугольники 3:4 и 16:9 двигаются вместе с областью, но медленнее (примерно в 2 раза) по сравнению с двумя другими прямоугольниками.

Вложу ниже текущую реализацию, в которой сетка представлена изображением и перемещается по области. Однако сама реализация неверна, поскольку разрешения не подстраиваются под область.

[image: текущая реализация]

Comment: добавте минимальную реализацию с не работаюшим алгоритмом

Comment: @Armen, не понял тебя, сюда добавить что-ли?

Comment: ну да, вроде логично, нет? как без этого я смагу исправить? мне же не повтороно делать?))

Comment: @Armen Залил сюда: https://drop.xtrafrancyz.net/xp0cixp0ek.zip

Comment: @euorohans гляну дам знать, но старайся минимализировать пример, и можно прямо сюда добавить просто те участки кода которые отвечают за это(михины, тема, и все такое это явно не нужное) ps: когда создаеш вопрос там есть место куда можно добавить участки кода

Comment: еще этот момент не понятен мне, по другому можеш обяснить 'Если пользователь переместит область, например, в левый верхний угол, все соотношения должны подстроиться так, чтобы область оказалась вверху слева.'............ он переместил белый квадрат в верхний угол и что то должно случится с линиями или?

Comment: либо какой то пример из какого то сайта, либо рукаписный/програмнный рисунок ожидаемого результата

Comment: @Armen Вот у нас, например, стартовая позиция с пересечением двух рандомных форматов. Зеленый квадрат - видимая область (их пересечение) https://drop.xtrafrancyz.net/7ivcm15d7k.jpeg

Comment: Я беру и перетаскиваю эту область выше и левее. Получается вот так https://drop.xtrafrancyz.net/d2d1w2k9f4.jpeg

Comment: Соответственно, вертикальная линия сместилась левее. Горизонтальная - выше. А зеленая область выше и левее

То же самое нужно сделать, но с 4мя форматами (1:1, 3:4, 16:9, 16:5)

Comment: готово. там в компоненте чутка стили подпортил пока разбирался(так что исправление оставлю на тебе).

Comment: @Armen спасибо, но это никак не решило мою проблему.

Comment: зайди сюда и посмотри чего не хватает https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-shadow-lx9584?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A23%2C24